# Prism Forms doesn't have OnNavigatingTo anymore. How to run some code before Views's constructor?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

Look at the code below. There's two DelegateCommand that are set in Views's constructor:

```
    public DelegateCommand DeletePromotionCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand EditPromotionCommand { get; set; }

    public PromotionDetailViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService pageDialogService)
        : base(navigationService, pageDialogService)
    {
        Title = "Promoção";

        DeletePromotionCommand = new DelegateCommand(DeletePromotion, CanDeletePromotion);
        EditPromotionCommand = new DelegateCommand(EditPromotion, CanEditPromotion);
    }
```

The CanEditPromotion is called when the EditPromotionCommand is set in the constructor. CanEditPromotion method is shown below:

```
    private bool CanEditPromotion()
    {
        var userString = Preferences.Get("user", string.Empty);

        if (userString == string.Empty)
            return false;

        var userId = (Guid)JObject.Parse(userString)["id"];

        if (userId == Promotion.CreatedBy)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Note that on the 4th sentence I need the Promotion property. This property need to be set before the Views's constructor, so it will be null and, at exactly line, it will break the app.

Before I should use the code below to set Promotion property, but Prism doesn't have OnNavigatingTo method anymore. Promotion info comes from the Page before and is passed as a parameter navigation:

```
    public override async void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);

        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            Promotion = parameters["promotion"] as Promotion;

            var marketService = new Service<Market>();

            Market = await marketService.GetAsync(Promotion.MarketId);

            IsBusy = false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

When I try to use INavigatingTo at my BaseViewModel, it is show to me a message saying to use IInitialize instead. I tried but the Initialize method is still fired after the View's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

As is indicated in the official release notes for Prism 7.2 `OnNavigatingTo` was deprecated due after a lot of consideration and feedback from the Prism community. This was in part due to the fact that OnNavigatingTo was expected to run to Initialize your ViewModel prior to the View being pushed onto the Navigation Stack. The issue is that over time its intent was getting lost and people were trying to misuse the API. The only way for us to move forward was to remove the reference to `INavigatingAware` from `INavigationAware` which unfortunately creates a soft break in which `OnNavigatingTo` simply isn't called. In the case where you have a direct reference to `INavigatingAware` you will get a hard compilation error.

To migrate your code you should use the new initialization API with either `IInitialize`, `IInitializeAsync` or `IAutoInitialize`. Assuming that you simply use IInitialize you'll update your legacy code from:

```
public void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    // your code here
}
```

to the new IInitialize version

```
public void Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Keep in mind that if you use the Async version of this the long running task will have to complete before the page is pushed thus causing a noticeable delay in navigation. It may often be more desirable therefore to simply use `async void` to avoid blocking the Navigation.

You can read more in the Prism 7.2 Release Notes [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v7.2.0.1367)

Comment: Nether Initialize or InitializeAsync method run before the constructor. I need a way to set Promotion property before the app runs the constructor.

Comment: That's not how the language works... nor was it how OnNavigatingTo worked. The constructor HAS TO run first so that we have an object that we can work with. Initialize will run before the Page is pushed onto the Navigation Stack.

Comment: It makes sense! Thank you, Dan!

Comment: @DanSiegel I ended up upgrading Prism without reading the release notes. OnNavigatingTo failed and this caused a bug. It took a while to track this down, I could imagine not detecting a bug like this (in an App with many pages). Usually packages add a "deprecated" tag for changes like this (with a message like "Please use IInitialize"), was this not possible for this situation?

Comment: No it wasn't really possible. As I mentioned in the answer OnNavigatingTo came from INavigatingAware which is what was deprecated. This was something that was added to INavigationAware. it wouldn't really make sense for us to leave the deprecated interface on INavigationAware. It wasn't something we did lightly and we had a lot of conversations with members of the community. The feedback we got was overwhelming that they preferred the hard behavior break to get the better API.

Comment: What about RaisePropertyChanged of ViewModelBase?

Comment: @Blarzek I have no context about your question... also it appears to be completely unrelated and should probably be it's own question

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this way:

At CanEditPromotion I put a null verification for Promotion property:

```
    private bool CanEditPromotion()
    {
        var userString = Preferences.Get("user", string.Empty);

        if (userString == string.Empty)
            return false;

        var userId = (Guid)JObject.Parse(userString)["id"];

        if (Promotion != null && userId == Promotion.CreatedBy)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

And I observe the Promotion property when the EditPromotionCommand is set:

```
    public DelegateCommand DeletePromotionCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand EditPromotionCommand { get; set; }

    public PromotionDetailViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService pageDialogService)
        : base(navigationService, pageDialogService)
    {
        Title = "Promoção";

        DeletePromotionCommand = new DelegateCommand(DeletePromotion, CanDeletePromotion)
            .ObservesProperty(() => Promotion);
        EditPromotionCommand = new DelegateCommand(EditPromotion, CanEditPromotion)
            .ObservesProperty(() => Promotion);
    }
```

And I used the OnNavigatedTo method to set Promotion property:

```
    public override async void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            Promotion = parameters["promotion"] as Promotion;                

            var marketService = new Service<Market>();

            Market = await marketService.GetAsync(Promotion.MarketId);

            IsBusy = false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```